# How do i fetch data from mongodb after deployment onvercel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, next.js, vercel

I created an ecom store with Next.js and MongoDB as my database. Fetching of data in my localmachine works with using getServerSideProps, but on deployment it doesn't seem to work.

I attached the code

SUMMER FINE PAGE
This page fetches data from MongoDB in the summer fine collection, and it works as the getServerSideProps URL points to localHost.

```
`import React from 'react'
import Footer from '../component/Footer'
import Header from '../component/Header'
import Link from "next/link"
import axios from 'axios'

import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function SummerFine({ allProducts }) {
    const isServerReq = req => !req.url.startsWith('/_next');
    const router = useRouter()

    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <p className=" itemHeader ml-auto text-left">  <span className='cursor-pointer' onClick={() => router.push('/men')}>Men</span>  </p>
            <p className='itemHeader_Main text-5xl text-left'>SUMMER FINE SELECTON</p>
            <div className="grid productSection lg:grid-cols-4 md:grid-cols-3 sm:grid-cols-2 gap-4 mt-10">
                {
                    allProducts.map((summerFineItem) => (
                        <Link href={`/summerFineItem/${summerFineItem._id}`} passHref key={summerFineItem._id}>
                            <div className='productGrid ' key={summerFineItem._id}>
                                <img className='productImages' src={summerFineItem.images} />
                                <br />
                                <p className='itemName'>{summerFineItem.name}</p>
                                <br />
                                <p className='itemPrice'>    $ {summerFineItem.price}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </Link>
                    ))
                }
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
    let prodRes = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/products")
    return {
        props: {
            allProducts: prodRes.data
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the API for fetching

```
import dbConnect from "../../../utils/Mongo";
import Product from "../../../model/Product";

export default async function Handler (req, res) {
    const {method} = req
    // Connect to Database
    console.log("Connecting to the database...");
     await dbConnect()
    console.log("Database Connected");    
    
    if (method === "GET") {
        
        const allProducts = await Product.find()
        res.status(200).json(allProducts)
    }
    if (method === "POST") {
        try {
            const newProduct = await Product.create(req.body);
            res.status(200).json(newProduct);
            console.log("New Product created");
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).json(error);
        }
    }
}
```

the URL for the domain the website is to be hosted is https://lacostestore.vercel.app/
I think the issue is from the getServerSideProps

I want to be able to fetch data stores in MongoDB to the client after being deployed on vercel